# How can I convert Conll 2003 format to json format?

Tags: python, json, conll, doccano

I have a list of sentences with each word of a sentence being in a nested list. Such as:

```
[['EU', 'rejects', 'German', 'call', 'to', 'boycott', 'British', 'lamb', '.'],
 ['Peter', 'Blackburn'],
 ['BRUSSELS', '1996-08-22']]
```

And also another list where each word creesponds to an entity tag. Such as:

```
[['B-ORG', 'O', 'B-MISC', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-MISC', 'O', 'O'],
 ['B-PER', 'I-PER'],
 ['B-LOC', 'O']]
```

This is the basic ConLL2003 data but I'm actually using a different data with another language. I only showed this one as an example represantation.

I want convert this list of lists into a JsonL format where the format is:

```
{"text": "EU rejects German call to boycott British lamb.", "labels": [ [0, 2, "ORG"], [11, 17, "MISC"], ... ]}
{"text": "Peter Blackburn", "labels": [ [0, 15, "PERSON"] ]}
{"text": "President Obama", "labels": [ [10, 15, "PERSON"] ]}
```

So far I have managed to put the list of list into this format(json list of dicts):

```
[{'id': 0,
  'text': 'Corina Casanova , İsviçre Federal Şansölyesidir .',
  'labels': [[0, 6, 'B-Person'],
   [7, 15, 'I-Person'],
   [18, 25, 'B-Country'],
   [26, 33, 'B-Misc'],
   [34, 47, 'I-Misc']]},
 {'id': 1,
  'text': "Casanova , İsviçre Federal Yüksek Mahkemesi eski Başkanı , Nay Giusep'in pratiğinde bir avukat olarak çalıştı .",
  'labels': [[0, 8, 'B-Person'],
   [11, 18, 'B-Misc'],
   [19, 26, 'I-Misc'],
   [27, 33, 'I-Misc'],
   [34, 43, 'I-Misc'],
   [59, 62, 'B-Person'],
   [63, 72, 'I-Person']]}]
```

However, the problem with this is that I want to merge the IOB format together and create a single, start to end entity. I need this format to be able to upload the data on doccano annotation tool. I need the compound entities labeled as one.

Here is the code I wrote to create the above format:

```
list_json = []

for x, i in enumerate(sentences[0:2]):
    list_json.append({"id": x})
    list_json[x]["text"] = " ".join(i)
    list_json[x]["labels"] = []
    for y, j in enumerate(labels[x]):
        if j in ['B-Person', 'I-Person', 'B-Country'...(private data)]:
            word = i[y]
            wordStartIndex = list_json[x]["text"].find(word)
            wordEndIndex = list_json[x]["text"].index(word) + len(word)
            list_json[x]["labels"].append([wordStartIndex, wordEndIndex, j])
```

I tried converting the above format into the format I wan. ie. merging IOB tags. Here is what I have tried so far that didn't work.

```
new_labels = []

for y, i in enumerate(list_json):
    label_names = [item[2] for item in i["labels"]]
    label_BIO = [item[0] for item in label_names]
    k = 0
    for index in range(len(label_BIO)-1):
        
        if (label_BIO[index] == "B" and label_BIO[index+1] == "I") or (label_BIO[index] == "I" and label_BIO[index+1] == "I"):
            k += 1
    
    for x in range(len(i["labels"])-1):
        
        
        if i["labels"][x][2][0] == "B" and i["labels"][x+1][2][0] == "I":
            new_labels.append([i["labels"][x][0],i["labels"][x+k-1][1],i["labels"][x][2][2:]])
                
        elif i["labels"][x][2][0] != "I" and i["labels"][x+1][2][0] != "I":
            new_labels.append([i["labels"][x][0], i["labels"][x][1], i["labels"][x][2]])
```

The problem with this block of code is that I can't determine the length of the sequence for the consecutive sequences. So for each element of the list k is always stable. I need k to change for the next sequence in the same list.

Here is the error I get:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-93-420750229f93> in <module>
---> 19             new_labels.append([i["labels"][x][0],i["labels"][x+k-1][1],i["labels"][x][2][2:]])
     20 
     21         elif i["labels"][x][2][0] != "I" and i["labels"][x+1][2][0] != "I":

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I need to determine where exactly I should calculate k each time. K here is the length of the sequence where B follows I and so on.

I also tried this but this only merges 2 of the labels together:

```
new_labels = []

for y, i in enumerate(list_json):
    I_labels = []
    for x, j in reversed(list(enumerate(i["labels"]))):
        if j[2][0] == "I" and i["labels"][x-1][2][2:] == j[2][2:]:
            new_labels.append([i["labels"][x-1][0],j[1],j[2][2:]])
        elif j[2][0] != "I" and i["labels"][x+1][2][0] != "I":
            new_labels.append([j[0], j[1], j[2]])
```

Output:

```
[[26, 47, 'Misc'],
 [18, 25, 'Country'],
 [0, 15, 'Person'],
 [59, 72, 'Person'],
 [27, 43, 'Misc'],
 [19, 33, 'Misc'],
 [11, 26, 'Misc'],
 [0, 8, 'Person']]
```

But I need the 3 "Misc" labels to be one single label from index 11 to 43.

For anyone wondering: The reason I'm trying to this is because, I have already labeled some amount of the data and tested a prototype model and it seemed to give pretty good results. So I want to label the whole dataset and fix false labels, instead of annotating from scratch. I think this would save me a lot of time.

ps: I'm aware that doccano supports uploading in the ConLL format. But it's broken so I can't upload it that  way.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the sentences to pandas Dataframe with there respective entity tags and join them. Here is an [inspiration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72257686/11342377).

You can also look at [this](https://gist.github.com/InzamamAnwar/b8f15058c79200f85730e17c35263367) is your data is in usual CoNLL format