# IOB format merge

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in IOB format as below:-

| Name | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Alan | B-PERSON |
| Smith | I-PERSON |
| is | O |
| Alice's | B-PERSON |
| uncle | O |
| from | O |
| New | B-LOCATION |
| York | I-LOCATION |
| city | I-LOCATION |

I would like to convert into a new dataframe as below:-

| Name | Label |
| --- | --- |
| Alan Smith | PERSON |
| Alice's | PERSON |
| New York city | LOCATION |

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups by compare values `O`, remove `IO-` values in `Label` column and with helper groups created by cumulative sum aggregate `join`:

```
m = df['Label'].eq('O')

df = (df[~m].assign(Label=lambda x: x['Label'].str.replace('^[IB]-', ''))
            .groupby([m.cumsum(), 'Label'])['Name']
            .agg(' '.join)
            .droplevel(0)
            .reset_index()
            .reindex(df.columns, axis=1))
print (df)
            Name     Label
0     Alan Smith    PERSON
1        Alice's    PERSON
2  New York city  LOCATION
```